# ggplot2: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'X' not found (checked for spelling)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to plot the same variables from different dataframes onto one graph. I've been able to get this to work so far, but am now having difficulties despite using an identical structure.

```
MgNo_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_liq, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = MgNo), colour = "red") +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_Olv, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = MgNo), colour = "green") +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_Spn, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = MgNo), colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_Cpx, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = MgNo), colour = "purple")
print(MgNo_plot)
```

Works correctly and produces a plot as expected. I've essentially copied and pasted this and repeated it, changing the plot name and y variable:

```
mass_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_liq, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = `mass (gm)`), colour = "red") +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_Olv, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = `mass (gm)`), colour = "green") +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_Spn, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = `mass (gm)`), colour = "black") +
  geom_point(data = MgNo_Cpx, aes(x = `T (C)`, y = `mass (gm)`), colour = "purple")
print(mass_plot)
```

which returns the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'mass (gm)' not found
```

I have double checked my spelling and even used colnames(data) for all datasets:

```
> colnames(MgNo_liq)
 [1] "Index"         "T (C)"         "P (kbars)"     "log(10) f O2" 
 [5] "liq mass (gm)" "wt% SiO2"      "wt% TiO2"      "wt% Al2O3"    
 [9] "wt% Fe2O3"     "wt% Cr2O3"     "wt% FeO"       "wt% MnO"      
[13] "wt% MgO"       "wt% NiO"       "wt% CoO"       "wt% CaO"      
[17] "wt% Na2O"      "FeMgSum"       "MgNo"         
> colnames(MgNo_Olv)
 [1] "Index"        "T (C)"        "P (kbars)"    "log(10) f O2"
 [5] "mass (gm)"    "wt% SiO2"     "wt% TiO2"     "wt% Al2O3"   
 [9] "wt% Fe2O3"    "wt% Cr2O3"    "wt% FeO"      "wt% MnO"     
[13] "wt% MgO"      "wt% NiO"      "wt% CoO"      "wt% CaO"     
[17] "wt% Na2O"     "FeMgSum"      "MgNo"        
> colnames(MgNo_Cpx)
 [1] "Index"        "T (C)"        "P (kbars)"    "log(10) f O2"
 [5] "mass (gm)"    "wt% SiO2"     "wt% TiO2"     "wt% Al2O3"   
 [9] "wt% Fe2O3"    "wt% Cr2O3"    "wt% FeO"      "wt% MnO"     
[13] "wt% MgO"      "wt% NiO"      "wt% CoO"      "wt% CaO"     
[17] "wt% Na2O"     "FeMgSum"      "MgNo"        
> colnames(MgNo_Spn)
 [1] "Index"        "T (C)"        "P (kbars)"    "log(10) f O2"
 [5] "mass (gm)"    "wt% SiO2"     "wt% TiO2"     "wt% Al2O3"   
 [9] "wt% Fe2O3"    "wt% Cr2O3"    "wt% FeO"      "wt% MnO"     
[13] "wt% MgO"      "wt% NiO"      "wt% CoO"      "wt% CaO"     
[17] "wt% Na2O"     "FeMgSum"      "MgNo"
```

As case-sensitivity seems to be the fix in most posts I can't find a solution to this problem. Is there a relatively simple fix that I'm overlooking?

Comment: For this it would be handy to have your data, so could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Can you show us the results of `colnames()` for your all four of your data sets? Is it possible you have some kind of weird space character (e.g. non-breaking space)? It might be easier/more idiomatic to generate this plot by combining the data frames (`rbind` or `dplyr::bind_rows` or `purrr::map_dfr`) and using a colour aesthetic ...

Comment: Try `aes_string(...)` instead of `aes(...)`. Having said that, using, e.g. "mass (gm)" for a column name is exceptionally poor programming practice. Much better to give them valid R names (like `T` or `mass`), and then adjust the axis labels using `labs(x="T (C)", y="mass (gm)")`. Finally, creating the layers manually like this - with multiple calls to `geom_point(...)` is not the correct way to use ggplot.

Comment: Hi Both, thank you for your help. The error was due to the MgNo_Liq having the header "Liq mass (gm)" whereas all the others only had "mass (gm)". I missed this due to an assumption that the program that created the tables created identical headings. my apologies for your time!